# Filtering Association Based On Through Model Attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, associations, has-many-through

I have a model:

```
class Example < ActiveRecord

   has_many :bars
   has_many :foo, through: :bars

end
```

Each instance of `Bar` has an attribute called `value` which can be either 1,2,3 or 4.

How can I query an instance of `Example` to return all its `Foo` associations where the linking `Bar` model has a value of `3`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it will fetch foos by joining with bars anyway, something like this should work:

```
example.foos.where("bars.value = ?", 3)
```